# Failing to add a service reference in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I come across an issue with service.

So basically I have a webproject where i would like to add some external reference to a service, but when trying to add it, or when i try to discover (by clicking GO) i get an error:

```
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://webadress:port/wsdl/authentication-service.wsdl'.
The content type text/html of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wsdl:definitions name="authentication-service"
   targetNamespace="http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/authentication/1.0" 
   xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
   xmlns:auth="http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/authentication/1.0" 
   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
   xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <!-- ************************************** -->
   <!-- Copyright Alfresco Software, Inc. 2005 -->
   <!-- ************************************** -->
   <wsdl:types>
      <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.alfresco.org/ws/service/authentication/1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <element name="startSession">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="fa" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <element name="fp" type="xsd:string"/>
             '.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Basically i dont know what should I do know, how can i still access the service, what is the best way, and why i can't reference the service in VS?

The reference is something like this: `http://webadress:port/wsdl/authentication-service.wsdl` (it is external service which is not mine or anything)

When I open this url in browser i do get a valid xml to see ....

Any idea is always welcome

Comment: Can you open your reference address in a browser?

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention, when i open it in browser i get a valid xml stuff

Comment: Is it possible to share the exact address?

Comment: Do you have the WCF Activation Feature installed?

Comment: No I dont have any wcf feature instealled i think, im using visual studio 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have similar problem when adding external api references and sometimes it worked generating proxy classes using [wsdl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) tool . You could give it a try

Comment: i did try but still i get the same issue, when i run it it says this:  - The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information. If you would like more help, please type "wsdl /?".

Comment: i tried it with this command: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\wsdl.exe" /out:c:/WebService.cs /order http://webadress:port/wsdl/authentication-service.wsdl